# bingham plastic model implementation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, elasticity, implementation

I'm looking for a book/paper/code which describes the implementation of a [Bingham plastic](https://doc.simulationx.com/4.2/1031/Content/Libraries/NonNewtonianFluids/Fluids/Bingham.htm) fluid model. I've tried deriving the equations for implementation using the style of the 1d visco-plastic model for solids described in the first chapter of [Simo-Hughes](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b98904) but it seems to me that the analogy between solids and fluids is imperfect, because the Bingham plastic model lacks an elastic spring.

Edit: I'm looking for an exact implementation, not regularized, analogous to the return mapping algorithms of plasticity.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking. The constitutive equation is on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @SpencerBryngelson Yes, the constitutive equation is on Wikipedia. But I'm not "getting" how to translate that "if" in the constitutive relation into the viscoplastic framework presented in Simo-Hughes and other plasticity books.

Comment: There is a plethora of ways to solve this and some more involved. Often a regularized approach (like [Papanastasiou regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingham-Papanastasiou_model)) is used. I suggest editing your question with how you want to solve this, like what numerical method and kind of problems you are looking towards.

Comment: @Nachiket you should include the type of formulation you are hoping for in your question.

Comment: @wwfe I'm using the regularized model you mentioned. I'm looking for a more exact treatment in the spirit of the return-mapping algorithms used in elasto-plasticity.

Comment: @wwfe if you could point me to one of the plethora of ways that are more exact that the Papanastasiou model, I would be very grateful.

Comment: OpenFOAM has [Herschel-Bulkley model](https://doc.cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide-v10/transport-rheology) that is a generalization of Bingham plastic.

Comment: @Nachiket see https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-444-53047-9.00006-X for a overview, there is the regularization approach, the variational equality formulation, and the augmented Lagrangian approach.  There are some recent developments but most are still along those lines.

Comment: @wwfe Thanks. Will read.